a player can play many games and a game can be played by exactly by two players
I have 2 Django models (tables) Player and Game with a many to many relationship, and a third as a intermediate table between them that has player username as a foreign key (the username is the player's table primary key), a game_id FK, and an additional attribute score.
More than 2 players can have the same game.
How do I make every game be played by two players instead?
class Player(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='./app/avatars/', blank=True, null=True)
    is_online = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    game_theme = models.ImageField(upload_to='./app/themes/', blank=True, null=True)
    played_games_num = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Game(models.Model):
    mode_choices = {
        'classic': 'Classic',
        'vs_robot': 'Vs Robot'
    }
    difficulty_choices = {
        -1: 'Vs Player',
        1: 'Easy',
        2: 'Medium',
        3: 'Hard'
    }

    game_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    mode = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=mode_choices)
    difficulty = models.IntegerField(choices=difficulty_choices)
    game_date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    duration = models.IntegerField()
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Player, through='Player_game')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.game_id)

class Player_game(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['username', 'game']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.game_id)

Adding unique_together in class Meta didn't solve the problem.

Modify the Player_game model to have a unique constraint on the game field, ensuring that each game can only have two players associated with it.
Implement a custom validation method or override the save method to enforce the constraint programmatically.


Do you need the complications of a ManyToMany game to player connection with a constraint that only two players may play any one game?
You might find it easier to have two ordinary ForeignKeys, say player1 and player2 (or black and white where there is such an asymmetry). If these keys are nullable, one player null can describe a player wanting a game but waiting for an opponent. A game in progress or finished requires all three keys.
The downside is that this design breaks if you later want to introduce multi-player games with varying numbers of participants.
